# Confguring WPF application to call COM component

Tags: c#

- Is there an alternative to `CoInitialize()` in `C#/WPF` application
  to load and use `COM` components?
- Is there any settings I need to check while creating the `WPF`
  application for `COM` compliance?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this; you just need to know the ProgID of the COM component.

```
public static object COMCreateObject (string sProgID)
{
    // We get the type using just the ProgID
    Type oType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID (sProgID);
    if (oType != null)
    {                   
        return Activator.CreateInstance(oType);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Assuming you're working within the .Net 3.5 or 4.0 Framework, your WPF application can handle the creation and destruction of COM objects out-of-the-box, just make sure you're you're properly disposing of them.